# 3D image reconstruction from 3 Fixed Camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, directshow, direct3d

I see some 3D Facial devices that using 3 Camera and find the 3D picture of face.

[image]

> IS there any specific angle these camera should be fixed for this
>   calculation?
>
> Is there any SDK, or tools in this domain that could simplify producing 3D image
>   from these fixed camera?

Answer (score 0):

The less angle you have, the less information about depth you will get from the cameras. So an angle is important, but i cannot say it will need x° degrees.

Comment: So this tips is not an answer !

Comment: It's an answer to the question if there is an specific angle

Comment: this is very nice question and this is no answer !